# post data and file with axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to send *object* and a *file* with using `axios`. 
However, it seems that server cannot get data as I expected.

I tried to send *i.e* `state = {number: 1}` as data with a file at the same time.

```
//react js

let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.state.selectedImage);
    formData.append('data', this.state);
    axios.post('url is correct', formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    });
```

I just want to make sure that above is the right way to send data and file at the same time in client.

```
//node 
.
.
.
body: { data: '[object Object]' },
  files:
   { file:
      { name: '232217736.png',
        data: <Buffer >,
        size: 43015,
        encoding: '7bit',
        tempFilePath: '\\tmp\\tmp-1-1560804010093',
        truncated: false,
        mimetype: 'image/png',
        md5: '84c3c16304d6140d960789e7037fba43',
        mv: [Function: mv] } }
.
.
.
```

Above is what server got from client. However, I can not work with data.
The data doesn't display it's contents when I use `console.log()`, and I can not use any method that works for a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake sending the entire state object.
Objects have invisible `toString()` method that displays `'[object Object]'`. Try:

```
alert({a: 'a', b: 'b'}) // [object Object]
```

You can use `JSON.stringify`:

```
JSON.stringify({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
```

And use `JSON.parse` in the back-end.